# How to find a probability?

Tags: probability

Two ships, independently arrive, at the port in any time within $24$ hours ($0-24$h). Every moment of arrival of ships is equally possible within $24$ hours.

If the port can handle only one ship and if the $\text{ship}_1$ in the port retains $1$ hour, and $\text{ship}_2$ $2$ hours find the probability that a ship that arrives second will have to wait?

Comment: Hint:  draw a picture.  the probability space for the two arrival times is a square with side $24$ and one corner at the origin.  The events wherein  the second ship has to wait is contained in a "bad strip" between $x_2=x_1$ and $x_2=x_1+1$, the events wherein the first ship has to wait lies in a "bad strip" between $x_1=x_2$ and $x_1=x_2+2$.

Answer (score 4):

**Here's a simple way to solve the problem:**

First, notice that the probability $P$ that a ship has to wait is the sum of the probability that either ship, which we call $S_1$ and $S_2$, has to wait, i.e. $P=P_1+P_2$.
As lulu commented, a good way to figure out problems like these is to draw the situation. Below you can see my crude drawing where I wanted to figure out at what conditions $S_2$ has to wait.

To find the probability $P_2$ that $S_2$ has to wait, we find the shaded area and divide by the entire area of probability space ($24 h \times 24h$). To find $P_1$ we simply notice that this must be twice that of $P_2$, since $S_2$ takes up twice as much time in the harbor as $S_1$. So this means that $P=3P_1$.

[image]

Here's what I get (I suggest only looking when you have tried to solve it yourself):

> $P \approx 12.2 \%$

Comment: Lovsovs, you suggested 12.2, but I am receiving 72/576 = 12.5%                   Could You please post your solution?

Comment: @MarinaCurcic (12.2 is correct, but I first wrote 12.8) The problem lies in calculating the area of the strip; for a square of side length $n$, such a strip would have area $(n-1)+1/2$.

Comment: @MarinaCurcic Did you get it right, or should I include it in the answer?

Comment: think about this, your solution do not include the possibility that  ship1 arrive between 23 and 24 and ship2 the next day? or I am wrong?

Comment: @MarinaCurcic As the problem is stated, the next day shouldn't be included as it isn't in [$0h$ to $24h$].

Comment: @MarinaCurcic No problem :) If you found my answer useful you can accept it (it's the tick below the up/down-votes buttons) and make me a happy man!